# How do I get the Matrix theme colors (Lime-Green text over black background) on the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, themes, fonts, colors, desktop-background

On the terminal emulator, how do I get the Matrix theme colors (Lime-Green text over black background)?

I like the purple a lot, it matches my laptop. But for the terminal, I want green font. How is that possible?

Comment: And if you want the Matrix scrolling text in your terminal, look for `cmatrix`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to *'Edit'* > *'Profile Preferences'*. Then under the colours tab, untick the 'use colours from the system theme', and select *'Green on black'* from built-in schemes (or create a custom one):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I you want to do this in a tty, aka using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Or without changing settings from the program.
Enter the following into your terminal emulator:

```
echo -e "\033[32mGREEN"
```

To get white text back:

```
echo -e "\033[00mWHITE"
```