# How to change font color in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: fonts, system, colors

I want to change my system font to green lime.

Comment: system font or terminal font?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/536130/how-do-i-get-the-matrix-theme-colors-lime-green-text-over-black-background-on?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an app called "[Gnome Color Chooser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnomecc/)" that would let you change the system font color (and a lot of other stuff) on gnome 2. I have no idea if it works with Gnome 3 because last update was six years ago.